# Determine Big-O of a function inside while loop

Tags: function, while-loop, big-o, time-complexity, pseudocode

For a loop where the such function aFunction() inside the loop has a big-o of O(nlog(n)), how do you determine the worst case time complexity?

```
i ← 0
while (i < n)
   aFunction(...)
   i ← i+1
done
```

Comment: What are the arguments, do they depend on anything like `i` or `n`? Your code sample is too thin

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it deals with algorithmic time-complexity and no actual code is involved.  Consider cs.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 4):

Think about how much total work is being done here. Each call to `aFunction` takes time O(n log n) and you're calling it a total of n times. Overall, that makes for a total of O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) total work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not such simple. Each call takes `O(i log i)`. So to make sure you are right we have to sum all `i log i` from i=1 to n. (If i understood OP's question correctly)

Comment: @Everv0id From the provided pseudocode I couldn't tell if `aFunction` was being called on `i` or on `n` on each iteration. I assumed it was `n`, but you're right that if it's `i` on each iteration there's more math required here.